# Share a D3D 11 texture across GPUs

Tags: c++, windows, nvidia, direct3d, multi-gpu

The system is a laptop with 2 GPUs, Intel UHD 630, NVIDIA GTX 1070, running Windows 10.

My app is using D3D 11 and it’s **not** marked in driver properties as “use high-performance nVidia graphics”, and I can’t mark it so, see [this support article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3019314/error-generated-when-desktop-duplication-api-capable-application-is-ru) for the reason.

I need to pass a 2D texture from Intel to Nvidia GPU. Can’t do that because `ID3D11Device::OpenSharedResource` returns `E_INVALIDARG` with no further info from runtime, even with debug runtime.

Tried creating the texture on either GPU and opening on another one, upgrading to D3D 11.1 and using NT handles instead of normal ones, switching to more compatible RGBA format instead of BGRA (both devices created with BGRA support), specifying SHADER_RESOURCE and RENDER_TARGET bind flags as written in “Textures being shared from D3D9 to D3D11” section of [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/d3d11/nf-d3d11-id3d11device-opensharedresource), still same result.

Here’s the code:

```
HRESULT createSharedTexture( ID3D11Device* device1, ID3D11Device* device2, const CSize& size, ID3D11Texture2D** ppTexture1, ID3D11Texture2D** ppTexture2 )
{
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;
    ZeroMemory( &texDesc, sizeof( texDesc ) );
    texDesc.Width = (UINT)size.cx;
    texDesc.Height = (UINT)size.cy;
    texDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    texDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    texDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    texDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    texDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    texDesc.BindFlags = 0;
    texDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_SHARED;

    CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> tex1, tex2;
    CHECK( device1->CreateTexture2D( &texDesc, nullptr, &tex1 ) );

    CComQIPtr<IDXGIResource> res = tex1.operator ->();
    HANDLE h = nullptr;
    CHECK( res->GetSharedHandle( &h ) );

    // The following line always fails
    CHECK( device2->OpenSharedResource( h, IID_PPV_ARGS( &tex2 ) ) );

    *ppTexture1 = tex1.Detach();
    *ppTexture2 = tex2.Detach();
    return S_OK;
}
```

I thought Windows just powered off the Nvidia GPU but no, I’m able to render on both GPUs and copy data between them through system RAM. But that copy is too slow for my requirements, I'm copying FullHD textures at 140 FPS, from staging to dynamic textures, and observing very high CPU usage by Nvidia’s user-mode GPU driver.

Comment: I may be wrong, but you have two GPUs of different vendors that don't share the same memory. I don't see what other way there could possibly be to access a texture generated on one GPU from the other except for copying the data!? You can't make two completely different pieces of hardware magically share the same memory and understand each other's internal data layout just via some software setting!?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel DXGI exposes the API to share them across adapters, it's documented and supported.

If you want to know how it's implemented in drivers, read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/rendering-on-a-discrete-gpu-using-cross-adapter-resources

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?   I can't even get it to work with two Nvidia GPUs in the same box (separate working cards, not an SLI situation)

Comment: @AmmoGoettsch Negative, my code copies them through system memory. For that particular use case, my client only really needed FullHD at 30-60Hz, was fast enough that way.

Comment: Thanks for responding.   I really just wanted nvidia driver to do what it can to transfer things "sideways" without punting all the way back up to my user code.  I realize obviously it would have to come over the bus again to get from one card to the other, but I really didn't want to process it in user land.  Oh well.   

I have some contention problems with the GPU->CPU bandwidth if I pull it back (there is a heavy D3D game running at the time.)   Guess there is no way around it.  Except maybe hardware compressing on the nvidia card :)

Comment: @AmmoGoettsch Well, if you sure IO bandwidth is the bottleneck, and you don’t need it to be bit perfect, compression ain’t too bad.
If that thing is from/for compressed video consider NV12 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/recommended-8-bit-yuv-formats-for-video-rendering#nv12 if that’s for 3D rendering BC1 or BC7 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/texture-block-compression-in-direct3d-11